# Spark (Scala): Insert missing rows to complete sequence in a specific column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data source that comes in with certain rows missing when they are invalid.

In the following DataFrame, each user should have 3 rows, from index 0 to index 2.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("user1",0,true),
  ("user1",1,true),
  ("user1",2,true),
  ("user2",1,true),
  ("user3",2,true)
)).toDF("user_id","index","is_active")
```

For instance:

1. user1 has all the necessary index.
2. user2 is missing index 0 and index 2.
3. user3 is missing index 1.

Like this:

```
+-------+-----+---------+
|user_id|index|is_active|
+-------+-----+---------+
|  user1|    0|     true|
|  user1|    1|     true|
|  user1|    2|     true|
|  user2|    1|     true|
|  user3|    0|     true|
|  user3|    2|     true|
+-------+-----+---------+
```

I'd like to insert the default rows and make them into the following DataFrame.

```
+-------+-----+---------+
|user_id|index|is_active|
+-------+-----+---------+
|  user1|    0|     true|
|  user1|    1|     true|
|  user1|    2|     true|
|  user2|    0|    false|
|  user2|    1|     true|
|  user2|    2|    false|
|  user3|    0|     true|
|  user3|    1|    false|
|  user3|    2|     true|
+-------+-----+---------+
```

I've seen a separate and similar question where the answer to pivot the table so each user has 3 columns. But 1, that relies on the fact that index 0 to 2 exist for some users. In my real case the index is over a very large range so i cannot guarantee that after the pivot all columns would be complete. It also seems a pretty expensive operation to pivot, then un-pivot to get the second DataFrame.

I also tried to create a new DataFrame like this:

```
val indexDF = df.select("user_id").distinct.join(sc.parallelize(Seq.range(0, 3)).toDF("ind"))

val result = indexDF.join(df, Seq("user_id", "index"), "left").na.fill(0)
```

This actually works but when I ran it with real data (with millions of record and hundreds of values in index) it took very long and so I suspect it could be done more efficiently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if number of indexes is relatively small (hundreds should fit into node's memory) you can 1) count the max index (if it's not known) 2) use `groupBy` + `agg` on your `DataFrame` to propagate additional data rows

Comment: Mind elaborating on #2? I'm not familiar with how to propagate additional data rows in agg. Thanks!

Comment: oh, sorry I meant `groupByKey` + `flatMapGroups` from here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset

Comment: however, it's just a guess, I don't know how much faster (if not slower) it would be...

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?! I know it's been four years but I'm really stuck on the same issue!